# ElasticSearch Delete Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, rest-client

My query is this

```
q = '{ "script":"ctx._source.id = val", "params":{ "val":11316623} }'
   _id="11316623"
   response = JSON.parse(RestClient.post("http://mydomain:9200/monitoring/mention_reports/#{_id}/_delete", q))
```

it gives us

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 400 Bad Request (RestClient::BadRequest)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:230:in `process_result'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in `transmit'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'

    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'

from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
```

Please help me

Comment: "http://mydomain}:9200/monitoring/mention_reports/#{_id}/_delete" look at it your url domain name should not content any kid of special char like `"http://mydomain}"`

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache and test the same...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do in this way

```
 mydomain = "ec2-222-333-444-244.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
 q= '{ "script":"ctx._source.id = val", "params":{ "val":11316623} }'
 _id = "11316623"
 response = RestClient.post "http://#{mydomain}/monitoring/mention_reports/#{_id}/_delete", :q => q, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
 json_res = JSON.parse(response)
```

it should be

`RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', :param1 => 'one', :nested => { :param2 => 'two' }` in this format

Comment: it gives us                                                            from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:116:in `parse_url_with_auth'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:63:in `execute'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'

Comment: i am hitting this script     q = '{ "script":"ctx._source.id = val", "params":{ "val":11316623} }'
   _id="11316623"
      response = JSON.parse(RestClient.post(URI("http://mydomain:9200/monitoring/mention_reports/#{_id}/_delete"), q))
and it gives us above error

Comment: please post your errors it is hard to understand what parsing it wants

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 400 Bad Request (RestClient::BadRequest)

Comment: if it iis running in your locally then it should be `localhost` or any `IP`

Comment: ec2 sever domain like this ec2-222-333-444-244.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: it should be 

`RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', :param1 => 'one', :nested => { :param2 => 'two' }` in this format

Comment: `RestClient.post "http://#{mydomain}/monitoring/mention_reports/#{_id}/_delete", :params1 => q`   and `mydomain = ec2-222-333-444-244.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com `

Comment: i can,t understand this please specify in your answer.thanks in advance